# How can I select or target this "U" element inaction to write CSS for it?

Tags: html, css

I collected a pre-made slider & I need to change its one element's style. To achieve this I need to target/select this `"u"` element from bellow example code so I can write `css` for this `"u"` element.

My code is like bellow:

```
<div u="slides">

  //some codes here

</div>
```

My Question:

1. How can I select this `"u"` element so I can write some custom `css` for it.
2. What is the `"u"` attribute used for & ***what is its meaning?*** When we should use it?

*-Thanks in advance*

*Shihab*

Comment: that is some custom attribute that may be used from js, what do you mean by selecting in stylesheet? div with u attribute selector is div[u]

Comment: To select an element by attribute you will use one of the [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Comment: It's worth pointing out that [custom attributes should be prefixed with `data-`](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) (e.g `data-u="slides"`) in order to validate in HTML5. Browsers won't care either way. Whether or not validation is *actually* necessary is open to debate.

Comment: Hellow godblesstrawberry, div[u] is working. thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, this is not a standard html attribute. However, you can target it in css as follows:

```
div[u=slides] {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

See the example below:

```css
div[u=slides] {
  background-color: yellow;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div u="slides">
</div>
```